# JavaScript is not working on my computer (chrome, js activated)

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I just try to test a very basic program in javascript but on my computer it does not work. It works on other computer but not mine. I'm launching it on chrome which has javascript activated. There is my code:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>p5.js</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js" type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***script.js***

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(400,400);
background(0);
var x = random(0,200);
rect(x,x,(200-x)*2,(200-x)*2);
}
function draw() {

}
```

In my folder I have also an asset folder which is empty and my style.css is empty. With this code I am supposed to have a black square on my screen (the canvas) but there is nothing, and when I check the console on chrome nothing is written. Moreover, the first time I launched index.html a file named debug.log appears:

***debug.log***

> [0126/184004.266:ERROR:settings.cc(263)] Settings version is not 1

Why does this script work on other computer but not mine ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: When you say it works "on other computer but not mine," how are you verifying that?  Are you doing an exact copy?  Are you sure your `script.js` doesn't need to actually execute something rather than just define functions?

Comment: you shouldn't have the version in there, you really don't need the type attribute at all

Comment: you're also not doing anything in your script, function declarations are not function calls

Comment: I would start even simpler to rule a few things out. Just add: `<script>alert("test")</script>` (and take out the other scripts) and see if you get an alert.

Comment: @Marc here I intentionally wrote a code which only create a canvas but I have a lot of codes which works at my school but not at my home computer I edited which one of the code I use at school so I'm sure that they are the same and works somewhere else than my home.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I removed the type attribute but it still doesn't work.

Comment: well like I said, your script doesn't actually do anything. You need to call the function after you declare it. At the bottom of your script add `setup()`

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have nothing when I try your code.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Where do you want me to add setup() ? If it's at the end of script.js it doesn't change a thing

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>p5.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="application/javascript"</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  background(0);
  var x = random(0,200);
  rect(x,x,(200-x)*2,(200-x)*2);
}
function draw() {

}
setup(); // that is a function call
```

I tested this on Firefox and Chrome and it works. Javascript is interpreted by your browser, it has nothing to do with your computer. If the exact setup above doesn't work for you then check [here](http://www.activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/chrome). If JS is enabled and it still doesn't work then try removing the p5.js script. If that *still* doesn't fix it then reinstall Chrome (or even better switch to Firefox)

Comment: Sorry but this is not the right answer. You should never call P5.js functions yourself. Instead, you need to let the P5.js framework call them. It **might** work with this simple example, but you'll have other problems with e.g. `draw()` not being called 60 times per second. If `setup()` and `draw()` are not being called, that means you're not loading the library correctly. Please see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

All of your audio your files listed in the JavaScript code MUST be named as HTTPS, not HTTP. And obviously, that means the website(s) you are linking to (including yours) must be secure. That is, you need to have your security certificates, and make sure they are activated. It's a security issue with Chrome. I hope that helps. = -)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer would be correct if you were **not** using P5.js. But since you are, you should **not** call the `setup()` function yourself! Instead, you need to let P5.js do that for you automatically. It **might** work with this simple example, but you'll have other problems with e.g. `draw()` not being called 60 times per second. If `setup()` and `draw()` are not being called, that means you're not loading the library correctly.

You need to check your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for any errors, both in the JavaScript console and in the network tab.

My guess is that you're accessing your page as a `file://` URL, which can have problems. You need to run a local server and access your files that way instead.